# re-sizing textfields in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, resize, grid-layout

I'm kinda new to java swing and I'm trying to do this by hand for practice. In the following example, I have a setup where I have a GridLayout to display fields the way I want. But I need to re-size the text fields, since I don't want them to all be that constant size. I need some to be bigger or smaller. Is there a way to do this? Also is there a way to remove some of the padding after the labels?

```
public void setupFrame() {
    pnlTop.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4, 10, 10));

    lblClosetLoc.setText("Closet location:");
    lblPhone1.setText("Phone 1:");
    lblJackPaired.setText("Jack paired:");
    lblPhone2.setText("Phone 2:");
    lblCubicle.setText("Cubicle:");
    lblJackType.setText("Jack type:");      
    txtClosetLoc.setEditable(false);
    txtClosetLoc.setText("");       
    txtPhone1.setEditable(false);
    txtPhone1.setText("");      
    txtJackPaired.setEditable(false);
    txtJackPaired.setText("");      
    txtPhone2.setEditable(false);
    txtPhone2.setText("");      
    txtCubicle.setEditable(false);
    txtCubicle.setText("");     
    txtJackType.setEditable(false);
    txtJackType.setText("");        

    pnlTop.add(lblClosetLoc);
    pnlTop.add(txtClosetLoc);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhone1);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhone1);
    pnlTop.add(lblJackPaired);
    pnlTop.add(txtJackPaired);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhone2);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhone2);
    pnlTop.add(lblCubicle);
    pnlTop.add(txtCubicle);
    pnlTop.add(lblJackType);
    pnlTop.add(txtJackType);

    getContentPane().add(pnlTop);       

    setTitle("Test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(300, 300);
    pack();
}
```

Comment: Use `GridBagLayout` or `MigLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> re-sizing textfields in GridLayout

basic property of [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) is that resize its child in both direction and `fills` / `schrinks` all available area came from its parent

> Also is there a way to remove some of the padding after the labels?

pading are defined by [`.... 10, 10)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) in the `pnlTop.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4, 10, 10));`

> I need some to be bigger or smaller. Is there a way to do this?

have to look at [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) or [`SpringLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html)

Comment: I'm looking through the SpringLayout and it seems to be what i was looking for! thanks! :)

Comment: @user1732377 glad if help you, don't forget to set alignment for JLabel (SwingConstant), btw work for all JTextComponents

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is what I got after I made the form with SpringLayout. Please correct me if I have gone wrong somewhere:

```
public void setupFrame() {
    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();

    pnlTop.setLayout(layout);

    lblClosetLoc.setText("Closet location:");
    lblPhone1.setText("Phone 1:");
    lblJackPaired.setText("Jack paired:");
    lblPhone2.setText("Phone 2:");
    lblCubicle.setText("Cubicle:");
    lblJackType.setText("Jack type:");

    txtClosetLoc.setEditable(false);
    txtClosetLoc.setText("");

    txtPhone1.setEditable(false);
    txtPhone1.setText("");

    txtJackPaired.setEditable(false);
    txtJackPaired.setText("");

    txtPhone2.setEditable(false);
    txtPhone2.setText("");

    txtCubicle.setEditable(false);
    txtCubicle.setText("");

    txtJackType.setEditable(false);
    txtJackType.setText("");


    pnlTop.add(lblClosetLoc);
    pnlTop.add(txtClosetLoc);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhone1);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhone1);
    pnlTop.add(lblJackPaired);
    pnlTop.add(txtJackPaired);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhone2);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhone2);
    pnlTop.add(lblCubicle);
    pnlTop.add(txtCubicle);
    pnlTop.add(lblJackType);
    pnlTop.add(txtJackType);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblClosetLoc, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblClosetLoc, 1, layout.NORTH, txtClosetLoc);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtClosetLoc, 5, layout.EAST, lblClosetLoc);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtClosetLoc, 5, layout.NORTH, pnlTop);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblPhone1, 10, layout.EAST, txtCubicle);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblPhone1, 1, layout.NORTH, txtPhone1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtPhone1, 5, layout.EAST, lblJackType);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtPhone1, 5, layout.NORTH, pnlTop);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblJackPaired, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblJackPaired, 1, layout.NORTH, txtJackPaired);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtJackPaired, 22, layout.EAST, lblJackPaired);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtJackPaired, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtClosetLoc);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblPhone2, 10, layout.EAST, txtCubicle);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblPhone2, 1, layout.NORTH, txtPhone2);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtPhone2, 5, layout.EAST, lblJackType);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtPhone2, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtPhone1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblCubicle, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblCubicle, 1, layout.NORTH, txtCubicle);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtCubicle, 47, layout.EAST, lblCubicle);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtCubicle, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtJackPaired);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblJackType, 10, layout.EAST, txtCubicle);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblJackType, 1, layout.NORTH, txtJackType);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtJackType, 5, layout.EAST, lblJackType);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtJackType, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtPhone2);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.EAST, pnlTop, 5, layout.EAST, txtPhone1);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.SOUTH, pnlTop, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtJackType);

    getContentPane().add(pnlTop, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    setTitle("Test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocation(300,300);
    pack();
}
```